# How to filter raw where a box is empty in a google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'am trying to create a code that do 3 things :

1/ collect data from a specific spreadsheet

2/ delete row where the column A have no value

3/ write the result on an other sheet

So far, using some code sample I'have been able to create the list (1/) and to write it (3/) with this code :

```
function FILL_PROJ_004() {

  var DATA_COLLECTsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DATA_COLLECT");
  var PROJECTsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PROJECT");

  var DATA_COLLECTStartRow = 6
  var DATA_COLLECTColumnCount = 1 // column E
  var lrDATA_COLLECT = DATA_COLLECTsheet.getLastRow()
  var rangeDATA_COLLECT = DATA_COLLECTsheet.getRange(DATA_COLLECTStartRow,1,lrDATA_COLLECT-DATA_COLLECTStartRow,5)
  var valuesDATA_COLLECT = rangeDATA_COLLECT.getValues()

    for (let i = 0; i < valuesDATA_COLLECT.length; i++) { 

      PROJECTsheet.getRange(1 + i,1).setValue(valuesDATA_COLLECT[i][0]);
      PROJECTsheet.getRange(1 + i,2).setValue(valuesDATA_COLLECT[i][1]);
      PROJECTsheet.getRange(1 + i,3).setValue(valuesDATA_COLLECT[i][2]);
      PROJECTsheet.getRange(1 + i,5).setValue(valuesDATA_COLLECT[i][4]);
   
    }

}
```

But when I try to filter the line where column A is empty (2/) I get stuck.
I think it's because the `DATA_FILTERED` I create is "empty", as it show "null" value when a use a`Logger.log(DATA_FILTERED)`

here is the code :

```
function FILL_PROJ_004() {

  var DATA_COLLECTsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DATA_COLLECT");
  var PROJECTsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PROJECT");

  var DATA_COLLECTStartRow = 6
  var DATA_COLLECTColumnCount = 1
  var lrDATA_COLLECT = DATA_COLLECTsheet.getLastRow()
  var rangeDATA_COLLECT = DATA_COLLECTsheet.getRange(DATA_COLLECTStartRow,1,lrDATA_COLLECT-DATA_COLLECTStartRow,5)
  var valuesDATA_COLLECT = rangeDATA_COLLECT.getValues()

  

  var DATA_FILTERED = valuesDATA_COLLECT.map((r,i) => {
    if(r[0] === "") {
      return [];
   
    }

  })
  
  Logger.log(DATA_FILTERED)
 

    for (let i = 0; i < DATA_FILTERED.length; i++) { 

      PROJECTsheet.getRange(1 + i,1).setValue(DATA_FILTERED[i][0]);
      PROJECTsheet.getRange(1 + i,2).setValue(DATA_FILTERED[i][1]);
      PROJECTsheet.getRange(1 + i,3).setValue(DATA_FILTERED[i][2]);
      PROJECTsheet.getRange(1 + i,5).setValue(DATA_FILTERED[i][4]);
   
    }

}
```

So my question is :
Can you help me filtering the raw where the colmun A is empty ?

If you also have a trick to simplify the way I wrote the result, I will appreciate it too !
something like that might be possible right ? :

`PROJECTsheet.getRange(1 + i,[1,2,3,5]).setValue(DATA_FILTERED[i][0,1,2,4]);`

here is a sample of my data :

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | BELVEDERE MUSEUM | 31.5 | ANTHONY |
| 2D | BERGBAUMUSEUM OELSNITZ | 7 | ANTHONY |
|  | BERGBAUMUSEUM OELSNITZ | 7 | MAREIKE |
| 2D | CHATEAUX DE BAVIERE | 48 | MAREIKE |
| COMMUNICATION | CHATEAUX DE BAVIERE | 4 | MAREIKE |
|  | CHATEAUX DE BAVIERE | 52 | MAREIKE |
| 2D | DESIGN MUSEUM MÜNCHEN/DIE NEUE SAMMLUNG | 161 | MAREIKE |
| PROJECT MANAGEMENT | DESIGN MUSEUM MÜNCHEN/DIE NEUE SAMMLUNG | 22 | ANTHONY |
|  | DESIGN MUSEUM MÜNCHEN/DIE NEUE SAMMLUNG | 183 | ANTHONY |
| 2D | DHM BERLIN | 5 | MAREIKE |
|  | DHM BERLIN | 5 | MAREIKE |
| 2D | EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT WARSAW | 50 | MAREIKE |
| RECHERCHES | DIVERSES EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT WARSAW | 3 | MAREIKE |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Recommendation:

To filter your data, instead of `map()`, I changed it to `filter()` and used `setValues()`to write all values at once instead of iterating it using for loop with `setValue()`.

```
function FILL_PROJ_004() {

  var DATA_COLLECTsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DATA_COLLECT");
  var PROJECTsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PROJECT");
  var DATA_COLLECTStartRow = 6;
  var DATA_COLLECTColumnCount = 1;
  var lrDATA_COLLECT = DATA_COLLECTsheet.getLastRow()+1;
  var rangeDATA_COLLECT = DATA_COLLECTsheet.getRange(DATA_COLLECTStartRow,1,lrDATA_COLLECT-DATA_COLLECTStartRow,5);
  var valuesDATA_COLLECT = rangeDATA_COLLECT.getValues();
  var DATA_FILTERED = valuesDATA_COLLECT.filter(r => r[0] != ""); 
  PROJECTsheet.getRange(1,1,DATA_FILTERED.length,5).setValues(DATA_FILTERED);
}
```

Output:

[image: filter]

### Reference:

- [filter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)
- [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: thx for your answer, was "map" method not the best way to do such a filter, or was it just not able to do the filter ? Because I have found the code on an other post of stack and I would like to understand what is made for...

Comment: `filter()` is the best method to use when you are selecting certain items of an array that meet the condition of the function while `map()` returns a new array after performing the function to each element in an array. Since you are trying to filter data that has value in column A using`filter()` is suitable to use.